# Small tool to edit app settings

Tags: .net, xml, batch-file, config, appsettings

I need to small tool in Windows environment to change an entry in `appsettings.config`.

It can be a cmd tool which I can write a batch file on it.

Does anyone have a clue?
Thanks

Comment: Edit your post with the `appsettings.config` file contents. XML and batch aren't the best pair but it certainly can be done.

Comment: check this http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @npocmaka, xmlstarlet works very well. Problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xmlstarlet. :)
Thanks npocmaka

updates:

Here is a period of code I wrote to use xmlstarlet.

To change the file:

../bin/Config/%~1/appSettings.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="KillMobileService" value="0">
</appSetting>
```

to

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="KillMobileService" value="1">
</appSetting>
```

use

```
xml edit --pf --inplace --update "/appSettings/add[@key='KillMobileService']"/@value -v 1 ../bin/Config/%~1/appSettings.config
xml fo -t ../bin/Config/%~1/appSettings.config >../bin/Config/%~1/appSettings_new.config
del "..\bin\Config\%~1\appSettings.config"
ren "..\bin\Config\%~1\appSettings_new.config" "appSettings.config"
```

I use edit and format command.
IIS will restart when detecting this content change.

doc link for edit command: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html

doc link for format command: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s05.html

Problem solved. =w=